# Remove a class from the closest div with class

Tags: jquery, toggleclass, closest

I am having an issue removing/adding a class to the closest div with a class. Right now it toggles the class for all, and not for the closest.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnMoreInfo', function () { 
$(this).closest('div').find('.moreInfo').toggleClass('hide')
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
    <div class='moreInfo hide'></div>
</li>
<li>
    <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
    <div class='moreInfo hide'></div>
</li>
<li>
    <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
    <div class='moreInfo hide'></div>
</li>
<li>
    <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
    <div class='moreInfo hide'></div>
</li>
<li>
    <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
    <div class='moreInfo hide'></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use jQuery's [**`next()`**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method (assuming your HTML structure always looks like it does above):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnMoreInfo', function () { 
  $(this).next('div').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SmZZy/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **next** like

```
$(this).next('.moreInfo').toggleClass('hide');
```

Comment: Have you ever used the `after` method?

Comment: Why did you completely change your answer?

Comment: I thought that after has depricated one

Comment: The first line won't work ... next will find the next sibling, but it doesn't have a subnode of class moreInfo

Comment: the div has class moreInfo once see

Comment: But it doesn't have a subnode with that class. So .find() won't return any result

Comment: it found the div then it will toggle the class...see Zenith's fiddle,may it is same

Comment: NOT the first line! Only the second line of code in your answer will work. The first one is different. Try!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not do it, it didn't remove the class from any div :(

Answer (score 0):

$(this).next('.moreInfo').toggle();

you can also use slideIn and slideOut and toggle